# What does "layman's guess" mean?

Tags: expressions, sentence

I heard a colleague use the words layman's guess in a sentence "My **layman's guess** is...".

What does that mean exactly? Is it something like "I'm **not an expert** but I would guess that..."?

Comment: Yes, your interpretation of the probable sense of the expression is right on target. In most English dictionaries, you'll find a definition of _layman_ that fits well with this reading of the longer phrase "my layman's guess."